# The plug-in execution failed because the Sandbox Client encountered an error during initialization

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

My Dynamics CRM instance refuses to run plugins. Unfortunately I don't have physical access to the environment, I cannot debug or investigate. Only guess and instruct system administrator to try another approach.

I started from compiling sample plugins from MS CRM SDK and registering it. On the server it's possible to register in `sandbox` mode only. I don't have Deployment Administrator privileges.

Plugin is registered on `Create` message on `account` entity — in the way SDK asks to do. But following run time error blocks execution:

```xml
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The plug-in execution failed because the Sandbox Client encountered an error during initialization.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204748</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>The plug-in execution failed because the Sandbox Client encountered an error during initialization.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-04-10T07:53:37.9238143Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[SamplePlugins: Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.FollowupPlugin]
[0a47eeb7-b3a1-e211-8ab3-00155d008717: Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.FollowupPlugin: Create of account]
```

- I tried different types of plugins, either custom or samples from Microsoft, all the same — they fail on remote server.
- I tried the same plugins on local development server — they all succeeded.
- I tried to run Sandbox service on local development server under minimal privileges to reproduce the error locally, but it doesn't show up.
- I asked to run Sandbox service on remote development server under maximum privileges to resolve issue remotely, but in vain.

Could you please give me an clue, what I could try next, to fix the issue?

Comment: Rollup of the server and rollup of your environment? Which sdk version you are using?

Comment: @Guido Rollup 12, most recent SDK, `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.5.0.14 (15)` — on both versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that I was able to resolve by running a repair installation of CRM and reconfiguring the service accounts that each service was set up as.